# number of lines in UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text, uilabel, lines

I need to get the number of lines in a UILabel, so that I can move another UILabel to be at the bottom of the last line of text.
I have done:

```
int lines = [cellDetailTextLabel.text sizeWithFont:cellDetailTextLabel.font constrainedToSize:cellDetailTextLabel.frame.size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height /16;
```

but well it's not perfect because there are some cases when the UILabel is 3 lines long but the above code only returns 2, but this is not the case for all 3 lines of UILabels.

Comment: What's the division by 16 for?

Comment: 16 is the line height so you get the size in pixels, divide by 16 and then you get the number of lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to treat UILabel's text layout as a black box (it does fun things like auto-adjusting font size when the text gets too long).

Instead, consider using UIView sizing methods:

```
// Ask the label to shrink (or grow) until it fits its text:
[cellDetailTextLabel sizeToFit];
// Get the frame.
CGRect r = cellDetailTextLabel.frame;
// Move its origin to below cellDetailTextLabel
r.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(r);
// Set its size to the size of the second label
r.size = cellLabel2.frame.size;
// Finally, move the second label
cellLabel2.frame = r;
```

I've noticed some odd behaviour with text-sizing on iPhone 4 (occasionally labels are an extra line too high or so); I'm not sure if this is fixed in 4.1.

Comment: This is moving the detail text rather than the second label. I need the 2 labels in the vertical center of their parent view.